PCB mounted (soldered) pluggable Pins or Terminals
I'm trying to design a PCB that is pluggable into another PCB, each one being inside separate plastic enclosures. I'm having a hard time finding a component that I can solder on a PCB and that can make the connection to the other PCB. The plugs should be able to handle mains voltage and around 10 A of current, that's why they need to be inside the enclosure, in order to be safe to operate.
I can only find components that are made to plug two PCBs together but can only be used with both PCBs inside the same enclosure due to having very small pins.
A possibility would be power outlet female connectors and plugs, but that are solderable to a PCB, like the ones they use in Smart plugs, as can be seen on some Youtube Smart Plug Teardown videos such as this one.
It doesn't necessarily need to be pluggable into a power outlet, all I need are two connectors, one female and another male that are pluggable into each other that I can have soldered into a PCB. I tried searching for pluggable terminals but didn't have much luck.
So I would like if someone could give me a search keyword or a product link so that I can find these components, ideally in the JLCPCB's Parts Library, which is the PCB manufacturer I'm going to be using.

Is there a reason you don't want to use a panel-mount connector and wire it to the board? A mezzanine connector (if one exists in your size) would be difficult to mount in such a way that you would have acceptable ingress protection and will transfer mating forces directly to the board.

@vir The reason not to use a panel mount is make the assembly easier, just screwing the board to the enclosure instead of having to connect wires from the panel-mount connector to the board. But that could be a plan B.

My recommendation is still to use panel-mount but if you want to continue with this you should also edit the original question to include what other signals are being transferred, whether both sides need to be touch-safe for mains voltage, the distance between the boards, the distance between the board and the enclosure, and any other constraints or requirements. A board-mount D-sub style connector with power pins could work.

@vir I need 3 pins touch-safe, and another one that would be better to be touch-safe but not strictly necessary. But I think it is easier to make them all pluggable in the same mechanism (i.e. touch-safe)

@Burglups Can you point me to a product page with a plug and another with a socket, please? I could only find banana test sockets that are solderable to the board, but not plugs. I can only find plugs that are panel mounted.

@Burglups So I would screw the plug in a board pad, right? Is there any specific pad design constraint for this or can it jsut be a normal pad for through-hole components that would be soldered?

@Burglups I was thinking of exposing the copper traces so I could add solder on top because it is really hard to have a trace capable of carrying 10A in the limited area I have on the board.

Molex Minifit)?  Apparently available for board-to-board and rated up to 600VAC ... any use?

@jonathanjo Those connectors need the clip to lock in palce, otherwise they are really loose, right? If they need a clip, they could never be solderable on a board inside an enclosure and be unpluged, because it would impossible to press the clip. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You can try this tool to find a connector. It has lots of filters you can apply, maybe something works for you. https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

@eccentricOrange Thanks for the tip, will give it a try

Here is a method

Go to mouser or digikey
go in the connector section
choose an appropriate subcategory. In your case, I think two makes sense: "Board to Board & Mezzanine Connectors" and "Through Hole Pin & Socket Connectors"
Apply the current/voltage rating filters that make sense (example from board-to-board/mezzanine)
Check the results. Here is one that looks nice and sturdy: Hirose FX30B



Firstly, many thanks for your detailed answer, one of the most detailed so far indeed. The problem with those connectors is that one board could be live at mains voltage at the time of connection. Since the connector requires a huge hole on the enclosure, I have some concerns regarding it. Because due to the size of the Receptacles holes, it seems easy to get into contact with them. I tried Digikey but could not filter for 600V+ and by searching for "600V" I could not find any there. The quick connect terminals suggested by Voltage Spike seem to allow for somaller holes in the enclosure.

Probably the best thing is something like a terminal
Look at quick connect terminals, you can get them with SMT mounts or screw mounts. There are lots of options, here is some examples:
For the male side (there are different angles)

Source: https://www.keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p60.pdf
This one is a rivet, but you should also be able to put a pem nut into your pcb or a screw an nut to hold it in. There are solder-able versions of these, but I'd prefer a screw for strain relief.
Female side if you need right angle PCBs:

Source: https://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/Horizontal-Entry/3571/product_id/682
Female vertical.

https://www.keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p61.pdf
They are UL rated so you shouldn't have trouble there and I think they are 10A but that isn't apparent if that applies to that connector on the sheet.
Another option if you need high current is a pcb shunts, but these are probably too bulky for your application, but I wanted to show what exists.

https://lugsdirect.com/PCB-Shunts-and-Jumpers.html
Many people just end up machining something out of copper or sheet metal copper plate with two holes and then soldering or using a fastener to mount them to a PCB.

Many thanks for the detailed answer, considering both male and female (or  Receptacle and header) sides, with product references. In fact, using quick connect terminals already came to my mind. My problem was, in the case of through-hole terminals, I was afraid they might not stood completely vertical and, therefore, not align properly to connect both board, given that I want the enclosure hole to be as tight as possible, for safety, since one side could be live at mains voltage. But those SMD, due to having a flat board mounting surface, seem a lot more promising.

You may need something custom machined. You can get sheet metal cut at many machining places (https://www.oshcut.com/capabilities/) and bent. All you would need is a simple bracket with two holes for fastners, which would be easily drawable in a dxf. You could also probably make a solderable one also, but that would take some experimentation. If you like the answer (and other answers) be sure to use the voting system. Also make sure you pick your favorite answer before the deadline so the rep doesn't get lost.

You suggest something custom machined to replace the Quick Connect terminals you referred above? Don't you think the SMD quick connect terminals would align properly?

I've upvoted the best answers. Yes, I'll award the reputation, I'm just waiting to get as many answers as possible.

Thanks for participating!

I would probably use something like the below. If you don't need any cable whatsoever between the two you could shorten the wires and mount appropriately. As others have mentioned I would be careful not to stress terminations or the board.
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/schurter-inc/6182-0033/1787799
https://www.schurter.com/en/datasheet/9009

Hirose -> Category -> Power
You'll find options here.
